# Eclipse taking too much to change tabs

Tags: eclipse

I have a weird problem with Eclipse and developing for android. 
When I have multiple .xml files opened and when I try to change from one tab to an other tab it takes like 3 seconds, it's really annoying. I have already turned off the "Automatic Compile" but it keet taking ages!

I'm on windows 7, on a i5 with 4gb of ram... I have enough power here I think!

Any idea?

Comment: which release of eclipse do you have?

Comment: Eclipse + laggy ui, who would have thought...

Comment: Juno, I'm updating as @AHungerArtist said!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.2 (Juno) version of Eclipse had major slowness issues (in particular, doing the exact kind of thing you are describing). The 4.2.2 (also known was 4.2 SR2) version should have fixed most of those. If you're on 4.2, you need to make sure and get the latest updates.